# The methods in linqts seem to be undefined

Tags: angular, linq, typescript

I am learning Angular4 and currently am struggling with enabling linqts to work.
In my `room-list.component.ts` I import it like this:

```
import { List } from 'linqts';
```

a few lines below I have my component class defined like this:

```
export class RoomListComponent
{
    public Rooms: List<Room>;
```

this still works just fine. `Rooms` gets assigned by other code returned from signalR request like this:

```
this._roomService.GetListResult.subscribe((rooms: List<Room>) =>
{
    this.Rooms = rooms;
});
```

so I assume `List` is working (as I replaced all the declarations of `Rooms: Room[]` to `Rooms: List<Room>`), but... When I do any code like this (the function doesn't matter: `Select, Where, etc.`, nothing works):

```
Rooms.Add(...
```

it says something like this `errors.ts:42 ERROR TypeError: _this.Rooms.Add is not a function`. Moreover it goes completely mad if I do something innocent like this (taken directly from linqts main examples):

```
let arr = new List<number>([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

suddenly it throws two errors:

`zone.js:1057 GET http://localhost:56040/Angular/linqts 404 (Not Found)` and

`Unhandled Promise rejection: Fetch error: 404 Not Found
  Instantiating http://localhost:56040/Angular/linqts
  Loading http://localhost:56040/Angular/Appjs/components/room/room-list.component.js
  Loading app ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Fetch error: 404 Not Found
  Instantiating http://localhost:56040/Angular/linqts
  Loading http://localhost:56040/Angular/Appjs/components/room/room-list.component.js
  Loading app
    at fetch.js:37
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:392)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:142)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
    at <anonymous> Error: Fetch error: 404 Not Found
    at http://localhost:56040/Angular/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1475:13
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:56040/Angular/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:392:26)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:56040/Angular/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:142:43)
    at http://localhost:56040/Angular/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:873:57
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:56040/Angular/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:425:31)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:56040/Angular/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:192:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:56040/Angular/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:602:35)
    at <anonymous>`

**What am I doing wrong?**

I also tried googling for any problems related to linqts, but I am pretty sure it has nothing to do with it, more like for some reason it doesn't find the functions (although navigating with F12 in VS2017 is a success). I would then guess it has been imported in a wrong fashion, but how do I tell? Last assumption was that it was unimported completely, but the code doesn't compile if I remove the `import` part, thus this assumption is wrong.

Comment: some sort of pluker that replicating your issue would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, when you declare where certain libraries are placed, you need to provide the full path. In `systemjs.config.js` the mapping was declared like this (WRONG!):

```
var map = {
    'linqts': '/Angular/node_modules/linqts',`
```

rather than this:

```
var map = {
    'linqts': '/Angular/node_modules/linqts/dist/linq.umd.js',`
```

I found a similar issue and the solution in [here](https://github.com/kuuurt13/ng-block-ui/issues/8)